# Can some one help me create a trigger for auto creating 5 child records when parent record stage is closed

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

Hi I tired creating below trigger but it is giving me this error:

> Loop variable must be of type CSM_Milestone__c

```
trigger CSMMilestone on CSM_Milestone__c (After insert, After update) {

     List<Opportunity> oppList = [select Id from Opportunity where StageName = 'Closed: Won']; 

     list<CSM_Milestone__c> csmList = new list<CSM_Milestone__c>();
     for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
     {
        CSM_Milestone__c csm = new CSM_Milestone__c ();
       // quote.Opportunity = o.id;
        csm.Name = 'CSM Milestone1'; 
        csmList.add(csm);
        if (o.StageName == 'Closed: Won'){
           for(Opportunity act: oppList){
              csm = new CSM_Milestone__c(Name='testName');
             // quote.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
              csmList.add(csm);
           }
        }     
     }
     insert csmList;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code to create object in opportunity. In for loop you can give your logic to create your records same like opportunity

```
trigger CSMMilestone on Opportunity(After insert, After update) {

list<Opportunity> csmList = new list<Opportunity>();
 for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
 {
    // if you want to create record in opportunity
    if (o.StageName == 'Closed: Won'){        
    Opportunity csm = new Opportunity();
     csm.Name = 'CSM Milestone1'; 
    csmList.add(csm);
    }     
 }
 insert csmList;    
 }
```

Comment: Will this work for if I have Parent object as Opportunity and child Object as CSM Whenever Opportunity stage is closed won , It will auto create multiple csm child records like name = a1, b2,c3,d4 etc

Comment: I am getting same error Loop variable must be of type CSM_Milestone__c

Comment: Trigger cmsMilesrone on csm_milestone__c(after ...) And in for loop for (csm_mileatone m : trigger.new) ... try ths..That should work

Comment: Sorry for formatting i am using mobile right now

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. I really appreciate it. But still I am getting same error. Please help